# How to retain the values of form after submit

Tags: php, form-submit

```
<?php
    $member_results = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT distinct(M.ID), M.NAME FROM .............");
    oci_execute($member_results);
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="report-page-form-form" class="clearfix"  onclick="changeValue();">
    <div class="member-drop-report">
        <label>Filter by Member:</label>
        <select name="memberorg">
            <option value="0">Any Member Organization</option>
            <?php 
                while( $data = oci_fetch_assoc($member_results) ){ 
                    echo "<option value=\" $data['ID'] \">$data['NAME'] </option>";
                } 
             ?>
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="date-input-report clearfix">
        <label>Start Date:</label><input type="text" name="start-date"  id="start" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="date-input-report clearfix">
        <label>End Date:</label><input type="text" name="end-date"  id="end" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly>
    </div>
    <input class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

I am using this form to submit data. The form works fine. But the values are cleared on submit. How can I retain the submitted values in form after submit? I am using  jQuery date-picker for both start and end date.

Comment: Add a php to your inputs like :

    `<input type="text" name="start-date"  id="start" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" <?php if (isset($_POST['start-date'])) echo $_POST['start-date'] ?> readonly>`

Comment: @Dukeling..i tried your code. But still the `placeholder` `YYYY-MM-DD` is showing after submit

Comment: So replace by that : `<input type="text" name="start-date" id="start" <?php if (isset($_POST['start-date'])) {echo $_POST['start-date']} else echo 'readonly placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"' ?> >` you'll have a placeholder and a readonly ONLY if there is nothing in it

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your code:

```
$start_date = (isset($_POST['start-date']) ? $_POST['start-date'] : '');
```

And in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="start-date"  id="start"  value="<?=start_date?>" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly>
```

Comment: Thanks Lvil. I modified your code and found a solution for date fields `$start_date = (isset($_POST['start-date']) ? 'value='.$_POST['start-date'] : 'placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"');` `<input type="text" name="start-date" <?php echo $start_date; ?> id="start"  readonly>`. How to fix for select list?

Comment: @drup: the same: "$memberorg = (isset($_POST['memberorg']) ? $_POST['memberorg'] : '');"  and in html: "<select name='memberorg' <?=($data['ID'] == $memberorg ? 'selected' : '')?>"

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post" id="report-page-form-form" class="clearfix"  onclick="changeValue();">
        <div class="member-drop-report">
        <label>Filter by Member:</label>
        <select name="memberorg">
        <option value="0">Any Member Organization</option>
        <?php while( $data = oci_fetch_assoc($member_results) ){ ?>
          <option <?php if ($_POST['memberorg'] == $data['ID']) { ?> selected="true" <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $data['NAME']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select> 
        </div>
        <?php 
        $start_date = (isset($_POST['start-date']) ? 'value='.$_POST['start-date'] : 'placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"');
        $end_date = (isset($_POST['end-date']) ? 'value='.$_POST['end-date'] : 'placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"');
        ?>
        <div class="date-input-report clearfix"><label>Start Date:</label><input type="text" name="start-date" <?php echo $start_date; ?> id="start"  readonly></div>
        <div class="date-input-report clearfix"><label>End Date:</label><input type="text" name="end-date"  id="end" <?php echo $end_date; ?> readonly></div>
        <input class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```